# canvas,drawArc angle issue

Tags: java, android, math, canvas

Cant figure out the proper angle for canvas.drawArc with known point on oval, my math is:

[image]

the issue is that I'm always getting overlapping in oval when angle!=180 || 90 :

[image]
[image]

yet, works on circle:
[image]

so it looks like I'm missing something. Can anyone help with that, please?

Comment: Looks like you are using a scaled local coordinate system somewhere. Please add more history on how you get the lengths `a,b`, how you draw the ellipse, how you draw the line.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you use the formula

```
(x,y) = ( rx*cos(phi), ry*sin(phi) )
```

then `phi` is not the angle of the point `(x,y)`. If you want to recover `phi` from measured coordinates `(x,y)`, use the formula

```
phi = atan2(y/ry, x/rx)
```